# Is it possible to set two remote urls for a git repository?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-push

i am using **bitbucket** and **my local server** and planning github too as remoteservers.

so is it possible to set these as remote urls.

so that when a single **git push** will push the code to all the remote servers. and also other members can clone the project from any of these servers and when they use **git push** it will push to all the remote servers too.

Comment: Check out using Git hooks. ***http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-3.html***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a remote and give it multiple URLs.

In your project's `.git/config`.

```
[remote "everyone"]
url = local
url = bitbucket
```

Comment: thank you very much. this solves a lots of time for me. it works fine. here is what i done: `gedit .git/config` then added line `[remote "everyone"] 
 url = https://suhailvs@bitbucket.org/suhailvs/jobsite.git
 url = suhail@192.168.0.201:/home/github/jobsite` then in terminal `git push everyone nositepacks`

Comment: @suhail No worries, and enjoy Bitbucket :)

Answer (score 0):

To do it all in a single `push` create a master repository and a second one and on the master add a post commit hook that will sync your secondary repository.  See the examples in your .git/hooks directory to read the book [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).